# Adding a sub row in table view cell

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am working on a project in which I am making a to-do-application and I am making it on table view where I give the functionality an add button on each cell and on click of that button I want to add a child cell in hierarchy to the clicked cell and same for all cells. 
Can you please tell me how to do this? I  will be very thankful.

Thank you in advance.
Here is a code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
     if (cell == nil)
     {


        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
     }





    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeContactAdd];
    button.tag = indexPath.row;
    button.frame = CGRectMake(280.0, 10, 25, 30.0); // x,y,width,height

[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonclicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell addSubview:button];

    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:cell action:nil];
    longPress.delegate = self;
    [cell addGestureRecognizer:longPress];

    int count = 0;
    if(self.editing && indexPath.row != 0)
        count = 1;
    NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i,%i",indexPath.row,(indexPath.row-count)]);

    // Set up the cell...
    if(indexPath.row == ([_choices count]) && self.editing)
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = @"ADD";
        return cell;
    }

    NSString *choice = [self.choices objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = choice;



    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Do u want to just add a cell below the clicked cell??Because there is nothing like child cell. You can customize it to look like one.

Comment: yes i want to add cell in heierarchy.

Comment: @Priyanka: in tableView numberOfRows what you are returning ??

Comment: @Priyanka: You need NestedTableView ??

Answer (score 0):

On the action of button add this code

```
[yourTableViewObject beginUpdates];
```

in DidSelectRowatIndexPath , get the index to be inserted.

```
NSIndexPath *insertPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row inSection:indexPath.section];
```

Insert the row at IndexPath :-

```
[yourTableViewObject insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:insertPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];

[yourTableViewObject endUpdates];
```